# Tensorflow populating placeholder with an array

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having difficulty populating a placeholder with a tensor. I've searched but can only find values with single values being supplied into the computation graph.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [ [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1] ]
labels = [ 0, 1, 1, 0]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 1], name="inputs")
W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name="hidden1")
b = tf.Variable(np.ones((2,4)), name="b", dtype=tf.float32)



with tf.Session() as sess:
  input_data = np.random.rand(2, 1)

  feed_dict = {
      x:input_data
  }

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(feed_dict)

  print(x.eval(session=sess))
```

gives me the following error:

```
has invalid type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, must be a string or Tensor.
```

I have also tried defining the placeholder as a tf.Constant:

```
input_data = tf.constant([[0],[1]], dtype=tf.float32)
```

This gives me a different error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'inputs_54' with dtype float and shape [2,1]
 [[Node: inputs_54 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[2,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I just want to supply an 2 x 1 matrix like this [[0],[1]] but it's proving difficult.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to evaluate the tensor `x`, it has to be part of the `sess.run`,

You need to call,

```
 print(sess.run(x,{x:np.array([[0],[1]])}))
 #x is the tensor you want to execute, 
 #feed_dict: feeds the input to the placeholder
```

Comment: But you're supplying a whole dictionary into a single placeholder. Does this mean you could init a few values at once by supplying an array instead of just x if you wanted to?

Comment: Also I am struggling with this. Can you please provide the full code sample with your changes? I need the input to be [[0],[1]]

Comment: then u need to feed the inputs as `print(sess.run(x,{x:np.array([[0],[1]])}))`

Comment: Thanks I'll try that when I get home

Comment: Yea that works. For the purposes of clarity (for other users) it may be better to amend the example in your answer to include the new answer within the context of the full code from my initial question. If you do this I'll upvote. Thanks :)